# it possible to generate the rss feed from a website that didnt provide rss

Tags: python, web-scraping, feed, rss-reader

I want to know if it's possible to use Python or any other way to generate an RSS feed for a website, if the site does not provide RSS feeds.

Are there any examples?

Comment: There are several online sites that claim to be able to build an RSS feed out of a page after you give them some CSS specifiers and some such (show them where the items are for the feed). It seems like a great idea to me, but I haven't had much luck in getting them to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if I would build something like that I would design it like this.

1. Write a Flask server which would handle request.
2. On every request download data from the target website with bs4.
3. Transform the data to XML output according to RSS format.

It's a bit more than just short code, but nothing very hard.